# Insert Multiple Rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, insert-into

Suppose we have an insert script that is consist 10000 statement like following;

```
Insert into CATEGORIES(CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_NAME, DESCRIPTION, PICTURE)
Values(1, 'Beverages', 'Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales', 'beverages.gif');

Insert into CATEGORIES(CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_NAME, DESCRIPTION, PICTURE)
Values(2, 'Condiments', 'Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings', 'condiments.gif');
```

So how can I insert all the rows simultaneously? If I use ";" I can insert row by row but I don't want to insert this way. Or If I delete ";" I get error.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is not duplicate. I want to learn how can I insert at a time without 10000 statement edit

Comment: That's precisely what the linked question is about

Comment: Then the answers in the duplicated proposed will definitely help you

Comment: This is not duplicate. Reference link valid for just 2-3 row, I mentioned for 10000 rows. 10000 rows can not edit so I want to learn practical way